# How is configuration shared/isolated in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, properties, scheduling, jobs, isolation

so, I have my spark context sc, from that I get my spark sql context,

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2")
```

Sometimes I want to use 2 for the shuffle partitions, but at some other moments(may be concurrently) I want to have 200.
This sqlContext is shared among all my threads, how do these properties isolate between executions? Are they global?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For isolating properties among different executions a new SQLContext can be obtaining by issuing newSession() on the SQLContext itself.
That way, everything you do with the newly created context exists within the context and dies there.